# Recall a php function in sql query. Update columns

Tags: sql

I need to update the column of a table.

I have this:

ID |       title       | slug_name

---

1 | The Winner is     |

---

2 | Beautiful day     |

---

I've to update the slug_name:

ID |       title       | slug_name

---

1 | The Winner is     | the-winner-is

---

2 | Beautiful day     | beautiful-day

---

So I created a function `slug()`

```
function slug($str) {
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $str), '-'));
}
```

and how can I return "title" in the function "slug"?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET slug_name = '".slug(???title???)."'");
```

I tried also:

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM table");
while($item = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET slug_name = '".slug($item->title)."'");
}
```

But all rows return the same "slug_name".

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing parameter, in order that MySQL updates and specific row, you need to specify that row attribute Either the ID or title with a WHERE closure in your function.

```
    function slug($str) {
    return "UPDATE table SET slug_name ='" . strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $str), '-')) . "' WHERE title ='" . $str . "'";
}
```

Now make it Clean:

```
   function slug($str) {
    $new_string  = "UPDATE table SET slug_name ='";
    $new_string .= strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $str), '-'));
    $new_string .=  "' WHERE title ='" . $str . "'";
    return $new_str
}
```

Comment: After replace function slug() with your function, I've to paste this? `$items = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM table");
while($item = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET slug_name = '".slug($item->title)."'");
}`